# Include a class in inline code block in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm playing around with inline code blocks in asp.net.  Can somebody tell me why the following code doesn't work?

```
<%@ Language="C#" %>
<%
    Response.Write(TestClass.ShowMessage());

    public class TestClass
    {
        public static string ShowMessage()
        {
            return "This worked!!";
        }
    }
%>
```

I get the following error message: CS1513: } expected

Comment: Inline code blocks are mostly for compatibility with Classic ASP. If there's no particular reason you're playing with them, I'd suggest you skip over them and play with something more useful.

Comment: My requirements called for a quick solution that an .aspx file with inline code handled perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think to be able to write a whole class you need to place it inside a  tag block

```
<script runat="server" language="C#">
//Put your class here
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You’ve got the `Response.Write` floating there outside of a function.

Why are you not placing this code in a script tag:

```
<script runat="Server">
    public class TestClass
    {
        public static string ShowMessage()
        {
            return "This worked!!";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then:

```
<%=TestClass.ShowMessage()%>
```

Note the `<%=expr%>` is handled specially.

Many consider this to be an impure approach. You could do this:

```
<script runat="Server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        litMessage = TestClass.ShowMessage();
    }
</script>
<asp:literal id="litMessage" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I kind of like the second example. I think it is nice to know. Thanks.